# SonarQube Specific Build and Report Generation

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarscanner

I am currently using `SonarQube Enterprise Edition - Version 8.7.`

Is there an option to somehow get a specific sonar report as opposed to just "latest"?

And is it possible to have scan or SAST reports generated/exported in pdf or html format?

For audit reasons, it would be nice to get a link or report that's specific for the codebase at that snapshot in time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the aggregated details of projects using:

1. [Portfolio](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/portfolios/)
2. [Application](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/applications/)